# Post loops with Wordpress + Advanced Custom Fields + WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display an ACF field within a Wordpress loop using functions.php to create a shortcode. Unfortunately, the_field('conference_location') does not display.

```
function show_conferences_func() {
  global $post;
    $html = "";
    $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'product_cat' => 'conferences'
  ));
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    $html .= "<div class=\"conference-block\">";
    $html .= "<h2>" . get_the_title() . " </h2>";
    $hmtl .= "<p>" . the_field('conference_location') . "</p>";
    $html .= "<a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\" class=\"button\">Learn more</a>";
    $html .= "</div>";
  endwhile; endif;

  return $html;
 }
 add_shortcode( 'show_conferences', 'show_conferences_func' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
`get_field('conference_location')`
instead of 
`the_field('conference_location')`

the_field() echo your data. So you're not storing your value.

Comment: Like this? I tried this, but had no luck:

`if( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
    $html .= "<div class=\"conference-block\">";
    $html .= "<h2>" . get_the_title() . " </h2>";
    $hmtl .= "<p>" . get_field('conference_location') . "</p>";
    $html .= "<a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\" class=\"button\">Learn more</a>";
    $html .= "</div>";
  endwhile; endif;`